# Getting ResultSet from loop while adding it to List

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a `List` getter method that returns a `ResultSet`. Everytime the `ResultSet` loops this was added to `List`. But in my `ActionListener` I have a loop that changes the values everytime and also it gives another `ResultSet`. How can I avoid `List` to create another instance when calling the getter method?

```
public List <Model> get(Model model) 
{
    String query = "{call get(?,?,?,?)}";
    List <Model> list = new ArrayList();

    try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(query);)
    {
        cs.setInt(1, model.getName());
        cs.setString(2, model.getPosition());
        cs.setString(3, model.getDepartment());
        cs.setString(4, model.getDate());

        try(ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery())
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Model m = new Model();

                m.setIn(rs.getString(1));
                m.setOut(rs.getString(2));

                list.add(m);

            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Error "+ex.getSQLState());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Calling this in action listener.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
    model.setName("Anything");
    model.setPosition("Jr");
    model.setDepartment("It");
    model.setDate(myList.get(i));

    DAO.get(model);
}
```

As you can see here loop gives new value everytime it loops. My problem is getter method resets to zero after executing one row at resultset loop.

Comment: Keep a "total" list in your calling code, and add the results of `get()` to that list on each iteration?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes exactly. By the way I already the issue is already solve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to gather the elements from all `get()` invocations, there are two solutions.

Either collect the returned elements into a single list in the calling loop:

```
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
    model.setName("Anything");
    model.setPosition("Jr");
    model.setDepartment("It");
    model.setDate(myList.get(i));

    list.addAll(DAO.get(model)); //Get elements, and add them to the list
}
```

... Or change `public List <Model> get(Model model)` to `public List<Model> get(Model model, List<Model> list)` and instead of creating a new list for each invocation of `get()`, pass it the same list:

```
public List<Model> get(Model model, List<Model> list) 
{
    String query = "{call get(?,?,?,?)}";

    try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(query);)
    {
        cs.setInt(1, model.getName());
        cs.setString(2, model.getPosition());
        cs.setString(3, model.getDepartment());
        cs.setString(4, model.getDate());

        try(ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery())
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Model m = new Model();

                m.setIn(rs.getString(1));
                m.setOut(rs.getString(2));

                list.add(m);

            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Error "+ex.getSQLState());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then invoke `get()` like this:

```
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
    model.setName("Anything");
    model.setPosition("Jr");
    model.setDepartment("It");
    model.setDate(myList.get(i));

    DAO.get(model,list);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution # 2 and absolutely works. It's also readable. Thanks :)